# PHP - Why while(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query())) loops?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

So I have the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE level = 2";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($write = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo ''.$write['username'].'';
}
```

I want to make it more simple so I do:

```
while($write = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE level = 2"))){
echo ''.$write['username'].'';
}
```

Why the first code isn't infinity looping and the second code is?

Comment: Because the `mysql_query()` gets rerun in each loop.

Comment: Q: why is the sky blue? A: read the docs

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ)

Comment: I can see the confusion. Most functions you are able to nest in this way.

Comment: Because every time your query is executed so it makes loop infinite

Answer (score 4):

the first code iterates a resource given by `mysql_query($sql);`

the second iterates the query and loads the first row each time forever.
so instead of going to the next row, it makes a new query and starts on that row.

As a side note - dont use `mysql_*` functions. Use `mysqli_` or `pdo` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your query is inside which tells the while to execute the query again and again. If you are looking for a much simpler alternative, you can try using an ORM such phpactiverecord.