# I'm trying to create a reusable php function with parameters to select data from tables in my database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a PHP function that has two parameters ($table_name + $limit) that both name the table I'm selecting data from and limit the number of results to display in the HTML document respectively. The problem is, when I substitute the function for the $data variable in my HTML doc, I get errors. The function I made so far is:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');

mysql_select_db('website');

function data($table_name, $limit){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name LIMIT 0, $limit";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

return $result;

}

?>
```

My HTML doc looks like this:

```
<?php while($header_headlines = mysql_fetch_array(data(headlines, 5))){ ?>

<nav>

<ul>

<li><?php echo $headlines['Headlines_Image']?></li>

</ul>

</nav>  

<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: `$header_headline` != `$headlines`. also, strings in function parameters need to be quoted (single or double) - `data('headlines', 5)`

Comment: (1) doing a `mysql_query()` inside a `mysql_fetch_array()` will cause an endless loop, as on each `while` loop it will do a new query instead of fetching the next row - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249861/php-why-whilemysql-fetch-arraymysql-query-loops (2) `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Update to `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: a better approach would be to make your function return all the database rows in an array result set. Then you would just loop over the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fetch data and return it from the function instead of fetching it in view, furthermore you will face problems making query inside mysql_fetch_array()

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');

mysql_select_db('website');

function data($table_name, $limit){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name LIMIT 0, $limit";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$arr = array();
$result_arr = array();

while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$result_arr[] = $arr;
}

return $result_arr;

}

?>
```

No in html view

```
<?php $data =data('headlines', 5); ?>
<?php foreach($data as $item){ ?>

<nav>

<ul>

<li><?php echo  $item['Headlines_Image']?></li>

</ul>

</nav>  

<?php }; ?>
```